# wamp icon partially red

Tags: wampserver

**i have installed wamp server on my system but i was unable to start wamp server** 
even all the services has started (my sql & apache) but still i was not be able to start wamp
server. i have check port 80 which is not in use.

Please Help..........

**Satish
India**

Answer (score 2):

You need admin rights to start wamp services

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have IIS installed on your machine: it does not allow you to run WAMP properly, so uninstall or deactivate it. You can find tons of guides to do that by searching on Google.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog which I have written which might resolve your problem. `https://rajiv2309.wordpress.com/2016/03/05/fixing-the-wamp-issue-when-the-tray-icon-is-red/`